# Plotting error in r: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, plot, na

I would like to plot a residualplot for my regression.
I want to plot it like it is done here (http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/simple-linear-regression/residual-plot) as:

```
model1 <- lm(ROA ~ LN_CO2, data=model1) 
model1.res <- resid(model1)
plot(LN_CO2, model1.res)
```

However, I have this error:

```
> plot(LN_CO2, model1.res)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I think it occurs, because while computing ´resid()´ missing values (NA´s) are omitted, and then model1.res and LN_CO2 dont have equal amount of data. Hence, plotting error.
If I am right, I still do not know how to use something like na.exclude, na.omit etc. 
Can someone help me?

EDIT:

My data looks like this (I have ~1200 obvervations):

Residuals:
`-1.345901 -2.124645 -3.614880 -4.703744  7.305482 -4.041825`

LN_CO2:
`7.278 7.872 6.902 7.296 8.173 8.335` 
(Sorry if it is not copy paste friendly, tried my best)

Comment: Can you please share your data in a copy paste friendly format?

Comment: 1. I tried to add my data.
2. Sorry, it does not work. The error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment (now deleted) pointed out, you wipe out your dataframe by saving the result of the fit to `model1`.  Don't do that.

You can use

```
fit1 <- lm(ROA ~ LN_CO2, data=model1, na.action = na.exclude)
```

to have the `NA` residuals included.  But the fit probably used `model1$LN_CO2`, which is not necessarily the same as `LN_CO2`, so that might also have been the cause of your problem:  a safer way to plot would be

```
fit1.res <- resid(fit1)
plot(fit1.res ~ LN_CO2, data = model1)
```

or

```
plot(model1$LN_CO2, fit1.res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe with your data and your  residuals, selecting only the complete cases :

`df <- data.frame(LN_CO2, model1.res)
df2 <- df[complete.cases(df),]`

then you can plot from there:

`plot(df2$LN_CO2, df2$model1.res)`

Comment: Thank you. I understand the logic of that approach, however, r does not.
Whilst building the first dataframe, I get the error that my argument implies different amounts of lines: 1432 and 1220.

Comment: The NAs are in the LN_CO2 column, right? what about `df <- data.frame(na.omit(LN_CO2) , model1.res)` and plotting from there?